# mutual information for power low distributed data?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, data-analysis, data-mining

I have a dataset  with power-low distribution, 
I would like to measure some kind of correlation/mutual information between the data to its class,(for feature selection task),
Can I use mutual-information in that case ?
If not, what other measures can I use?
Any reference to useful info will also be appreciated.

thanks